# How to Install Windows Server 2012 and Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on a Same Machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed Windows Server 2012 in my 3 Desktop PCs. I am using it for study purpose. In that PCs I need to install Ubuntu Desktop OS Like Dual OS. I searched in internet. All I got was Dual OS for Windows Server is possible with Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.

Please help me to find a solution to install Windows Server 2012 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Same Machine. Or else suggest me a Free OS Like Ubuntu which supports Dual OS with Windows Server 2012 in Same machine.

Thanks,
Rokesh

Comment: I think the Problem would be File system. Windows uses NTFS and FAT32 file system. Whereas ubuntu uses EXT4 file system. But, Not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, the easiest is to have two HDs, physically, witch would be safer, during the installation you could detach the drive with Windows Server, install Ubuntu and then reattach the Windows HD. If this is not a possibility you could use the Windows partition tool to remove a part of the NTFS, you will have to make some research on this. Since you don't say either or not you have tried to do that all i can say is what I usually do:

1 - Windows Installation:

- Boot from a flash drive containing the Windows.
- In the moment I can select the drive in which I will install the SO, choose to change It then remove the existing partition, confirm.
- Create a new partition with, in a case 
  like this, half the available size in the HD, install the Windows  normally.

2 - Ubuntu Installation:

- Boot from a flash drive with Ubuntu  installation files.
- Use the device boot list/options key, (in a desktop PC will be F8 key, in a notebook will vary, F11 and F12 are the most common).
- In the boot list choose de flash drive to boot, follow the initial parts of the  Ubuntu installation 'till the partitioning part.
- In the disk option choose the empty space in your HD. You can let Ubuntu automatically create the set for you or manually do it.

Case you decide to try manually, create one small partition, like up to 30% of the space to the mounting point /, a swap partition with twice the size of you RAM memory, all the remaining space can be assigned to the /home mounting point, this way you can reinstall Ubuntu formatting the system partition and keep your data on /home.

This [link](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), brought to us by [JHBonarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178/jhbonarius), have a detailed step by step to do it with Windows 10 and 8.1. With Windows Server should not be too different.

Comment: Could you format this properly, using bullet points and such, instead of just a big piece of text... And you're forgetting the part about disabling the secureboot. Look [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/).

Comment: Secureboot may not have this name or may not be present in some systems, mainly, I have not come across this particularity in the many times I've done this.